# How can I reduce server response time on my EC2 LAMP server?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, lamp

I just created a EC2 instance and installed LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm using AWS EC2 with 1 core processor and 1GB RAM. I have WordPress installed on it with its default theme. When I scanned my website on pagespeed insights, it is showing that I need to reduce my server response time.

I'm using PHP 7.1 and FPM for better performance and disabled `.htaccess`, yet no success. I tried finding to tune Apache performance but all the articles are almost same and nothing helped me.

Comment: We would probably need to see what mode you have configured Apache with presently, and what your response times are presently. Have you tried Apache's `ab` to get some response data? We would need to see this. Have you profiled your application?

Comment: Thanks @halfer, i didn't changed anything in apache server.It has all default configuration.I have wordpress installed and it is giving me about 27 second of response time now.I'm using apache's mpm_event with PHP7.1-FPM.

Comment: 27 seconds for one single request? OK, that's likely a problem in your WordPress set-up then - maybe a buggy theme, or a database that needs indexes? You will have to profile that to see where the problem is. Do you have the same problem with a local install?

Comment: I don't have a theme installed on m WordPress, it is just a default WordPress install.

Comment: Well, you will be using a theme, but the default one will not be the reason for the performance issue. There is not enough information in your post to debug why a single request is taking that long - do you have hundreds of thousands of posts or comments in your database, maybe?

Comment: No, i have only 2 posts on my wordpress, everything is at their default settings.I tried installing LAMP server many times and setup wordpress but after all i'm getting server response time isssues

Comment: Maybe try a profiling system like Blackfire? Hard to say on so little information. Are you sure it's a server problem rather than a slow connection to your Insights system?

Comment: I don't know the issue, how can i check if this issue is cauesed by slow connection or something else? I' using AWS EC2 with 1 core processor and 1GB RAM.I don't have anything on the server, it's just a new setup.I have a theme that is working fine on other EC2 instance on same speces hardware and PHP5.6. But the same theme is giving slow server response on pagespeed insights although i'm using PHP7.1-FPM which is much faster then PHP5.6.

Comment: Maybe SSH into the console so you can profile performance on localhost - you can run `ab` (Apache Bench) from there.